# BST lookup recursion function confusion about returns

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to understand recursion. This is a really basic question about implementing the lookup function for a BST in Python. This code is directly taken from this [post](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/binary-search-tree-library-in-python/).

In this example, the lookup function returns two values: (1) whether the value exists in the tree and (2) what the parent node of the value is if it is found in the tree.

Why do you need to do "return self.left.lookup(data, self)"? Why can't you just do "self.left.lookup(data, self)" without the return instead?

```
class Node:
    ...
    def lookup(self, data, parent=None):
        """
        Lookup node containing data

        @param data node data object to look up
        @param parent node's parent
        @returns node and node's parent if found or None, None
        """
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                return None, None
            return self.left.lookup(data, self)
        elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                return None, None
            return self.right.lookup(data, self)
        else:
            return self, parent
```

I have implemented a working version of lookup that does not give back the parent node of the value, below. The below works just fine without having to do a return of self.left.lookup():

```
def lookup(self, value):
    if(self.value == value):
        print("Found value!")
        return True
    elif self.value > value:
        if self.left == None:
            print("Value not found.")
            return False
        else:
            self.left.lookup(value)
    else:
        if self.right == None:
            print("Value not found.")
            return False
        else:
            self.right.lookup(value)
```

In the code below, I try to return both a boolean value for whether the value is in the tree as well as the parent node (like the original post does):

```
def lookup(self, value, parent=None):
    if(self.value == value):
        print("Found value!")
        return True, parent
    elif self.value > value:
        if self.left == None:
            print("Value not found.")
            return False, None
        else:
            self.left.lookup(value, self)
    else:
        if self.right == None:
            print("Value not found.")
            return False, None
        else:
            self.right.lookup(value, self)
```

This above code does not work, and I get the error: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". The TypeError disappears when I do "return self.right.lookup(value, self)" and "return self.left.lookup(value, self)", but I do not understand why. Why does adding "return" fix the code?

Comment: If there is no `return` then the function will return `None`. Guaranteed. So not only will the first call to `lookup` be `None` so will every other call to `lookup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a return statement python automatically returns None. You can test this in the python shell:

```
>>> def sum(a, b): a + b
>>> print sum(1, 2)
None
```

Adding the return statement tells python to give back the computed value to the caller:

```
>>> def sum(a, b): return a + b
>>> print sum(1, 2)
3
```

In your case what was happening is that the result was getting computed, but as soon as it ended it would be discarded since the intermediate calls to *lookup* didn't return the computed result.

To illustrate what's happening with a toy example, consider a simple recursive multiplication function:

```
>>> def mult(n, m, acc=0):                                                                                                                                                           
      if m == 0: return acc                                                                                                                                                        
      else:
        print("m %s: %s" % (m, acc))                                                                                                                                         
        mult(n, m-1, acc+n)
```

Here the intermediate call to *mult* doesn't return the result computed by the recursive step. Calling the function yield this output:

```
>>> print mult(3, 3)
m 3: 0
m 2: 3
m 1: 6
None
```

As you can see the result is getting computed, but as soon as the final result is ready, everything gets thrown away.

Adding the return statement:

```
>>> def mult(n, m, acc=0):                                                                                                                                                          
      if m == 0: return acc                                                                                                                                                        
      else:
        print("m %s: %s" % (m, acc))                                                                                                                                         
        return mult(n, m-1, acc+n)
```

yield the expected output:

```
print mult(3, 3)
m 3: 0
m 2: 3
m 1: 6
9
```

In general each step of a recursive function *MUST* return the result of the subsequent step either as is (tail recursion) or modified in some way.